# How to set chinese text into an edit field in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am new to using international languages in my win32 program in C++. I have a simple window created with an edit field inside. I want to set a chinese hardcoded text into the edit field. I am using SetWindowText but the output has only question marks and | character. What am I missing? My code file is pasted below. I have tried WM_SETTEXT but no luck.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";
    
    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    HWND edit = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Edit", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 0, 0, 200, 50, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowTextW(edit, L"銷售回扣");
    //SendMessage(edit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(L"銷售回扣"));

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The Chinese character literals are subject to the vagaries of the compiler character set. Use `\x....` notation instead.

Comment: Also, make sure the Edit control is assigned a Font that can display Chinese characters.

Comment: check the encoding of your cpp file. Better use UTF-8 with BOM